# Multidimensional Array in PHP (form data with checkboxes)

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I'm new to PHP and having a problem reading checkboxes submitted by a form. Before explaining it i would like to mention that i'm trying to edit a much larger application and the data cannot be sent in any other way. It's just a matter of finding a good method of reading what is being sent.

When a normal text input is sent, the form will post the following:

```
custom[0][type]="text"
custom[0][name]="VariableName"
custom[0][value]="VariableName"
```

Basically there is a main "custom" multidimensional array that has several elements (0,1,2,3 etc) and each element has name and value.

However, when one of the elements is a checkbox, the following stuff gets posted:

```
custom[1][type]="list"
custom[1][name]="SelectedOptions"
custom[1][value]="Value1"
custom[1][value]="Value3"
custom[1][value]="Value5"
```

Getting to the PHP side of things, this is the code i'm using to read the data sent by the form. The code below works ok in scenario 1 (with text based inputs) but only reads one value when we have list type custom data.

```
foreach($_POST['custom'] as $item){
    if($item['value'] != "") echo $item['name'].'='.$item['value']
}
```

The problem is that **$item['value']** only reads one of the values, not all 3. How can i get all 3 values in a variable ? It probably is a very easy thing...

To put it all combined, this is what it is sent with POST (3 checkboxes are checked for Variable2)

```
custom[0][name] Variable1
custom[0][type] text
custom[0][value]    ValueForVariable1
custom[1][name] Variable2
custom[1][type] checkbox
custom[1][value]    Value1
custom[1][value]    Value3
custom[1][value]    Value5
```

And this is what **print_r($_POST)** shows for the posted data above

```
[custom] => Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
    [value] => ValueForVariable1
    [name] => Variable1
    [type] => text
    )
[1] => Array
    (
    [value] => Value1
    [name] => Variable2
    [type] => checkbox
    )
```

Just to be sure we're all on the same page, the actual data is generated by a more complex system and we can't really change that. I'm interested in seeing how we can read all 3 values for Variable2 that are sent in the POST.

Thanks !

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST)` produce, exactly? (just for this chunk is ok)

Comment: checkbox name cant be correct if i understand your naming correctly.  checkbox name would have to be custom[1][value][] or you will overwrite the value with the last.

Comment: @jcmeloni - I have edited the question and added the print_r data.

Comment: @Rufinus - just with my basic php knowledge, a lot of things seem wrong in the system i'm working with, but now i have to make this work.

Comment: according to your print_r output im right, you only get one of your checkbox values, not 3.

Comment: @Rufinus . I know i only get one. How can i get all 3? The data is there in the POST as i can see it in firebug.

Comment: read my first comment again..... of course you can read it in firebug, its showing you what is sent, but when php assembels the arrays, it does exactly as i said... it overwrites the values.

Comment: @Rufinus is describing the problem accurately -- the values are being overridden because there's no bucket for the additional information to go into (like `custom[1][value][]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
With the extra information that you've since provided, I see that I originally misunderstood the problem.

Since you have no control over over the form that sends the data to your PHP script, and thus can't change it to ensure that the later checkboxes with the same name do not overwrite the earlier ones, you'll have to get access to and process the raw post data itself.

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo $postdata;
```

... will output the postdata just like a GET querystring: `blah=1&blah=2&blah=3` (blah indicates 3 form fields with the same name blah, the first two of which would be overwritten in `$_POST` leaving `$_POST['blah'] = 3`).
with a little exploding on `&` and looping and parsing looking for the variables in question, or even any conflicting variables, will get you where you're trying to go.

---

**Original Answer:**

HTML forms only submit checkboxes (or radio buttons) that have been checked.  If they haven't been checked, the browser won't send the data back to the server.

The main way to solve this is to know what you're looking for on the back end and test for it (i.e. `if (isset($_POST['checkboxname'])`).

If you truly need a general purpose backend that will dynamically incorporate all checkbox elements, checked or not, the way I've solved this in the past is to use javascript to record all form elements on the page and submit that info with the rest of the form (and, in my case, also submit whether that field was changed or not).

---

Here's a function that you can run at the top of the script to treat POST the way you expect it to be treated from your ASP background:

```
function post_process() {
    $rawpostdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
    if (!$rawpostdata) return;
    $fields = explode('&', $rawpostdata);
    $post = array();
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        list($key, $val) = explode('=', $field);
        if (isset($post[$key])) $post[$key] .= ','.$val;
        else $post[$key] = $val;
    }
    $_POST = $post;
}
```

Comment: or you use the oldest trick in the world and add a hidden field with the same name with value="0" (if checked value is 1) so you always get all fields, if the radio/checkbox is selected, the 0 value is overwritten.

Comment: @Jason As you can see in the posted data, 3 values are posted which means that 3 checkboxes were selected in the form page.

Comment: @Rufinus in my particular scenario I placed a premium on the same code working all the time without me having to remember to add (or change) a hidden field for every single field that existed (an intranet database application that has many hundreds of fields on dozens of pages), but you're right, in more limited (and more common) applications that might be more tenable.

Comment: @Cornel I see what you've got going on.  I may be able to get a solution for you...

Comment: @Jason: just a question of how you generate forms... in my applications i use abstracted/extended Zend_Forms and when i add an checkbox or radio the hidden field is printed automaticly.

Comment: @Jason Yes, that does the trick. I was hoping however that since I have only a limited knowledge of PHP there will be a better, nicer solution. 
Both Rufinus and jcmeloni explained that this is how PHP handles things (bad bad php, asp will put one value after another separated by comma and that makes more sense than just IGNORING posted values) and because the initial form is all dynamic, treating the entire POST as one large string is far from an ideal solution.
I'm editing the class that creates the form so that it will add the extra [] to the variable names. 
Thank you all !

Comment: I like the way PHP does things because it forces me to actually think about the data design when I'm building my forms, which leads (me, at least) to better code and less mistakes.

Comment: Because it's Saturday, and my wife and child are out of the house, and I can't mow the lawn because it's wet outside, I've written you a POST processing function that will treat the data the way you expected from your ASP background.  Appended to my answer.